# data manipulation in R: how many time did an individual spend within each period?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

In `R`, I have three time points

> time <- c(7, 1, 4)

and suppose that the time period is partitioned into three intervals: (0, 3], (3, 5], (5, 8]

```
breaks <- c(3, 5, 8)
```

---

`timeSpent` has one row for each observation and one column for each period. It gives the time spent by each observation in each period:

```
 timeSpent <- outer(X=time, Y=breaks, FUN=pmin)
 timeSpent <- cbind(timeSpent[, 1], 
                    sapply(X=1:(length(breaks) - 1), FUN=function(ii)
                      timeSpent[, ii + 1] - timeSpent[, ii]))

 > timeSpent
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    2
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    3    1    0
```

For example, observation 1 spent 3 days in interval 1, 2 days in interval 2, and 2 more days in interval 3. For observation 2, it spent only 1 day in interval 1, and nothing in the remaining intervals.

---

Would you have a more elegant way to obtain `timeSpent`?

Comment: How do you decide how much time an individual spends in one time period?

Comment: Take individual 1. He left after 7 days. Consequently, he went completely through periods 1 and 2 and partially through period 3.
In period 1, he spent: 3 - 0.
In period 2, he spent: 5 - 3.
In period 3, he spent: 7 - 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

We `cbind` a column of zeros to the `timeSpent` matrix so we can get the initial time spent in the first observation window, and `apply` the `diff` function across the rows...

```
res <- t( apply( cbind( 0 , timeSpent ) , 1 , diff ) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    2
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    3    1    0
```